# R save multiple files with different names

Tags: r, save, write.table

I have a variable named "data" which contains 10 lists, I want to save each list in different files (with different names).
I know how to save an individual file but not how to write code for doing it through a loop. My biggest problem is with the name of the files.

I would like a folder with files with these names: percentage0.01.bed, percentage0.02.bed...)

I'm trying something like this:

```
percentages<-seq(0.01,0.1,0.01)
>percentages
 [1] 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08 0.09 0.10
sapply(seq(length(data),function(x) write.table(data[x], sep= "    ", col.names=F, "/home//Desktop/percentage"+toString(cv[x]))
```

but it does not work...

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. I think your issue is in the path, string concatenation doesn't work like that in R. You may use `paste` or `sprintf`.

Comment: There are several issues (e.g. missing `)` after `length(data)`). Try `data <- replicate(2, data.frame(x=runif(5), y=runif(5)), simplify = FALSE); percentages<- 1:length(data); sapply(seq(length(data)), function(x) write.table(data[[x]], sep= " ", col.names=F, file=paste0("percentage", percentages[x], ".bed")) )`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might do better with a `for` loop here. Try:

```
mypath <- "/home//Desktop/percentage/"

for (i in seq_along(percentages)) {
  write.table(percentages[i],
    file = paste0(mypath, paste("percentage", i, "bed", sep = ".")))
}
```

Note that I can't debug the part of this that specifies your desired path. I tried a version on my machine, and it worked fine. But be sure to include that last `/`.

Answer (score 0):

saving multiple files with different names from data frame containing text.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
myfile<-paste0("file", "_", i, ".txt")
write.table(df[i,1],myfile,sep="\t",row.names=FALSE)
}
```