# Can I automate an increasing value in a file name in R?

Tags: r, loops, csv

So I have .csv's of nesting data that I need to trim. I wrote a series of functions in R and then spit out the new pretty .csv. The issue is that I need to do this with 59 .csv's and I would like to automate the name.

```
data1 <- read.csv("Nest001.csv", skip = 3, header=F)
functions functions functions
write.csv("Nest001_NEW.csv, file.path(out.path, edit), row.names=F)
```

So...is there any way for me to loop the name Nest001 to Nest0059 so that I don't have to delete and retype the name for every .csv?

Comment: Probably something similar to this: "R save multiple files with different names
" https://stackoverflow.com/q/33520138/9022665

Answer (score 1):

EDIT to incorporate Gregor's suggestion:

One option:

```
filenames_in  <- sprintf("Nest%03d.csv", 1:59)
filenames_out <- sub(pattern = "(\\d{3})(\\.)", replacement = "\\1_NEW\\2", filenames_in)
all_files     <- matrix(c(filenames_in, filenames_out), ncol = 2)
```

And then loop through them:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(all_files)) {
  temp <- read.csv(all_files[[i, 1]], skip = 3, header=F)
  do stuff
  write.csv(temp, all_files[[i, 2]], row.names = f)
)
```

To do this `purrr`-style, you would create two lists similar to the above, and then write a custom function to read in the file, perform all the functions, and then output it.

e.g.

```
purrr::walk2(
  .x = list(filenames_in),
  .y = list(filenames_out),
  .f = ~my_function()
)
```

Consider `.x` and `.y` as the `i` in the for loop; it goes through both lists simultaneously, and performs the function on each item.

More info is available [here](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html).

Comment: @Gregor--reinstateMonica-- Thanks for catching that! I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to put all of these CSVs into one folder, without any other CSVs in that folder. Then, you can write a loop to go over every file in that folder, and read them in.

```
library(dplyr)    

setwd("path to the folder with CSV's goes here")
combinedData = data.frame()
files = list.files()

for (file in files)
{
  read.csv(file)
  combinedData = bind_rows(combinedData, file)
}
```

EDIT: if there are other files in the folder that you don't want to read, you can add this line of code to only read in files that contain the word "Nest" in the title:

```
files= files[grepl("Nest",filesToRead)]
```

I don't remember off the top of my head if that is case sensitive or not